# When you prefer virtual functions over templates in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I was interviewed by a financial company and was asked this question:
**"List the case(s) when you prefer virtual functions over templates?"**

It sounds weird for me, because usually we are aiming the opposite right?
All the books, articles, talks are there encouraging us to use static polymorphism instead of dynamic.

Are there any known cases I was not aware of when you should use virtual functions and avoid templates?

Comment: Can you name some of the books and articles you quote? Also, the first argument evolves directly from the compile time vs. run time paradigm: With run time polymorphism you can re-use existing code without re-compiling. The implementing classes don't have to be known at compile time of the code using them, as opposed to the template solution where you need all the code. Which leads to the second argument against templates, long compile times and no compilation firewalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI / visualization widget toolkits are an obvious case. Re-implementing a `draw` method, for example, is certainly less cumbersome with virtual methods and dynamic dispatch. And since modern C++ tends to discourage raw pointer management, [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) can manage the resource for you.

I'm sure there are plenty of other hierarchical examples you can come up with... a base `enemy` class for a game, with virtual methods handling the behaviour of various baddies:)

The whole 'overhead' argument for dynamic dispatch is completely without merit today. I'd argue that the vtable indirection implementation hasn't been a significant overhead for serious workloads in decades. There's the more interesting question that if C++ was designed today, *would polymorphism be part of the language?* But that's neither here nor there now.

---

I don't like the chances of this question remaining open, as it's not a direct programming problem and is probably too subject to opinions. It might be a better question for [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

**When the type of the object is not known at compile time, use `virtual` methods.**

e.g.

```
void Accept (Fruit* pFruit)  // supplied from external factors at runtime
{
  pFruit->eat();   // `Fruit` can be anyone among `Apple/Blackberry/Chickoo/`...
}
```

Based on what user enters, a fruit will be supplied to the function. Hence, there is no way we can figure out that what is going to be `eat()`. So it's a candidate for runtime polymorphism:

```
class Fruit
{
  public: virtual void eat () = 0;
}
```

In all the other cases, always prefer static polymorphism (includes `template`s). It's more deterministic and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Interview question seems to asking for preference (& your reasoing).
I would prefer interfaces (virtual methods) for ease of creating mocks for unit testing. We can use template for these, but it is cumbersome (consumer has to be templated). If profiling shows no speed degradation with vtable lookups, prefer that over mocking/testing non-virtual methods.

Also, type erasure. I don't think it can be implemented at all using templates. Type erasure can be roughly thought of as void ptr and function pointers, which can be implemented easily using interfaces + virtual methods.

Templates need code implementation to be made available. I believe virtual methods of an interface can be invoked on a child ptr with just its binary (object) file.

Not sure if code bloat with template is an issue with modern compilers, but if executable size increases significantly, that could be an issue in embedded systems with limited memory and these would not prefer to use templates.